# J2ME Midlet showing Java Error on some phones

Tags: java-me, midp, midlet, midp-2.0

the APP is working fine on emulator but shows java error afer installing on some samsung phones

After install java screen appears and a dialog saying  java error

JAD file:

```
MIDlet-1: SuperRecharge, , com.pst.superrecharge.SuperRecharge
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 89564
MIDlet-Jar-URL: Super.jar
MIDlet-Name: Super
MIDlet-Vendor: Vendor
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.1
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
```

Comment: You will need to paste some code if anyone should have a chance helping you. Also tell us what Samsung model you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Probably,The Problem is in your Code..

Some Functions like setFullScreenMode(True) works on some Mobiles.

Try it on Another mobile,say,nokia and see if it works

Comment: it is working on nokia phones. problem is with samsung gt e2252,I stucked with it I wasted my whole day

Comment: So some functions in your program/code is not suitable or compatible for some samsung ...(Every Phone has its own Differences and Similarities)

Comment: how can I know those? I am using 3rd party library ksoap.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-win/html-helpset/z40005429112.html)..And also make sure your phone supports CLDC 1.1 and MIDP 2.0